# IPv4 -> IPv6 -- IPv6 -> IPv4 routing

Tags: networking, routing, ip-routing, dynamic-routing

I hope the is the right place to ask this question.  I'm just looking for the correct name of the type of network routing I'm attempting to implement so I can learn and implement it.

I'm using linux (Raspberry Pi3) that has the ethernet port and a USB Wi-Fi dongle to support an ad-hoc mesh (+babel) IPv6 network over WiFi, **this works fine, and the Pi's communicate.**

I want to route the ethernet traffic (one end the master that communicates to all the various slaves with single IPv4 ip each).

Topology is as follows:

```
                      _____                           _____
                      \ | /          IPv6             \ | /                                   
                       \|/  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  ~  \|/ ~  ~  ~  ~  ~ --> to next device (21, 22, 23...)
                        |                               |                                    
                   -----------                      ----------                               
                   |         |                      |        |                               
10.10.10.1/23------|   ???   |                      |  ???   |------ 10.10.10.20/0           
 (master)          |_________|                      |________|          (slave)
```

My question is, what kind of routing the (???) do I need to set up to forward packets from 10.10.10.1 to 10.10.10.20, 21, 23...
I'm looking for something where each of the slave devices don't need a special configuration and they figure that out themselves baised on a least cost metric or something similar.

*(If you're interested, this for for snowgun control at a ski resort that spans *miles* and I can probably reach from gun to the next closest gun, but no way I can reach all of the guns at the same time, speed is not much of an issue, it's just modbus telemetry).*

Comment: You'll have to set up some sort of tunnel, like a VPN.

Comment: Why on *earth* do you want to mix IPv4 and IPv6 in this way? Do IPv4 all the way or IPv6 all the way.

Comment: Okay, I'll do IPv4, it doesn't matter in this application.

Comment: Okay, I'll do IPv4, it doesn't matter in this application.

That still leaves the issue that the wireless ad-hoc NICs have their own IP's and the PLCs have a different IP I want to route to.

I'm looking for a way to have the enpoints talk back to possibly multiple (I hope for redunancy!) master feeds without individual routes in iptables for each and every one (notice it's a */23 subnet, I have a lot of them). 

I,ve looked at both tunnels and VPN, but neither do Least cost or loop prevention as far as I can tell.

Comment: It sounds to me that you want to create a `wireless mesh network`? That is all devices in the network is not neccessarily reachable directly from your location, but there exist a routing chain in the mesh network where you can reach all devices in the network by forwarding ip packages between nodes in the network until they reach the target you want to reach? It is definitely possible, though I do not have practical experience on the field. I **wanted** to write my master thesis in the field though, but ran out of time and money... :-/

Comment: I have the wireless mesh currently working fine in IPv6.
My question is how to route the endpoints (IPv4 via ethernet) into the "cloud" of WiFi in the most efficient way.

I'm looking for: IPv4 copper --> WiFi stuff happens --> IPv4.